# magnific popup not working In shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, magnific-popup, shopify-app

I am working on custom **magnific popup with shopify** site.In my **header.liquid** file am calling the magnific popup content.

```
<button id="open-popup" >Open popup</button>
<div id="my-popup" class="mfp-hide">
  popup  content here.
</div>
```

Here i have added the script in **theme.js.liquid**

```
$('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
  items: [
    {
      src: '#my-popup',
      type: 'inline'
    }
  ],
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  },
  type: 'image'
});
```

But It shows the following error

```
TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function
```

If anyone please tell me if **am i miss something like js library files**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am found the actual problem for this issue.Some of the themes having default magnific pop-up library in theme.js.liquid file.

My new theme brooklyn was having magnific pop-up library already.So it was working fine now.

So check with **theme.js.liquid** file having magnific popup library present or not.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that jQuery is included? if so, is it imported before magnificPopup?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue even though the magnificPopup code was included in my theme.js.

Don't ask me why - after wrapping the magnificPopup call in the window.onload it started working.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

  $('.open-popup').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    midClick: true
  });
}
```